# SQLAlchemy-serialize values into column of table

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project in SQLAlchemy. I've got `Command` class which has custom serialization/deserialization method called `toBinArray()` and `fromBinArray(bytes)`. I use it for TCP communication (I don't want to use pickle because my functions create smaller outputs).

`Command` has several subclasses, let's call them `CommandGet`, `CommandSet`, etc. They have additional methods and attributes and serialization methods redefinitions to keep track of their own attributes. I'm keeping all of them in one table using `polymorhic_identity` mechanism.

The problem is that there are lot of subclasses and every has different attributes. I have previously written mapping for every of them, but this way table has huge amount of columns.

**I would like to write mechanism that will serialize (using `self.toBinArray()`) every instance to attribute `self._bin_array` (stored in Binary column) before every write to DB and load (using `self.fromBinArray(value)`) attributes after every load of instance from DB.**

I have already found answer to part of my question: I can call `self.fromBinArray(self._bin_array)` in function with `@orm.reconstructor` decorator. It is inherited by every `Command` subclass and executes proper inherited version of `fromBinArray()`. **My question is how to automatize serialization on writing to DB (I know I can manually set `self._bin_array` but that's very troublesome)?**

P.S. Part of my code, my main class:

```
class Command(Base):
    __tablename__ = "commands"
    dbid = Column(Integer, Sequence("commands_seq"), primary_key = True)
    cmd_id = Column(SmallInteger)
    instance_dbid =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey("instances.dbid"))
    type = Column(String(20))
    _bin_array = Column(Binary)

    __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_on" : type,
    "polymorphic_identity" : "Command",
    }

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.fromBinArray(self._bin_array)

    def fromBinArray(self, b):
        (...)
    def toBinArray(self):
        (...)
```

**EDIT: I've found solution (below in answer), but are there any other solutions? Maybe some shortcut to insert event listening function inside class body?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that solution was simpler than I expected-you need to use event listener for `before_insert` (and/or `before_update` event). I've found information ([source](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html)) that

> reconstructor() is a shortcut into a larger system of “instance level”
>   events, which can be subscribed to using the event API - see
>   InstanceEvents for the full API description of these events.

And that gave me the clue:

```
@event.listens_for(Command, 'before_insert', propagate = True)
def serialize_before_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    print("serialize_before_insert")
    target._bin_array = target.toBinArray()
```

You can also use `event.listen()` function to ,,bind'' event listener to instance, but I personally prefer decorator way. It's very important to add `propagate = True)` in the declaration so subclasses can inherit listener!